# How to Bookmark lines before and after a regex matches until specific line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm sorry for this post title but I didn't find better title for this problem.
I have a list like following:

```
/////////////////////////
Mitnhnhnksmuion
2,687,064
Etyjyjes
1,897,331
Pihjloyd
1,466,137
Edddlnnnnney
1,297,624
Thjtyjkujkes
1,241,307
Fnnhhnac
1,159,710
AfdBhhhghghBA
1,113,062
Elnhhyhjkukjhn
1,023,500
Bggggggel
1,009,075
Letjyjnhhtrh
991,284
Bahtyjtjyjd
849,265
1980Q4
/////////////////////////
Eayes
4,228,223
Elhyjtyjey
1,456,729
1,412,750
Lein
243
184
AA
1,129
672
Elejntyj345hn
002,570
Neerthty34ond
916
78
Biwertetoel
910,353
Qen
874,812
Bs
877,293
Pyd
850,146
1978Q1
/////////////////////////
Mteichrtertson
2,747,969
Eatertglertees
1,885,332
Pirtertd
1,490,156
Elverts
1,295,789
TtrrheBerteaerttles
1,239,194
Fleterteter
1,156,907
ABB
1,117,183
E
1,027,583
Bi
1,010,372
LedZ
987,821
Barb
850,687
1980Q4
/////////////////////////
```

following regex bookmark some of above list lines:

```
(?:^|\R)\K\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=\R)
```

lines that bookmark with this regex:

```
1,456,729
1,412,750
243
184
1,129
672
916
78
```

but I don't like this! I want to bookmark my regex matches sections.
for example I want to bookmark following section in my list:

```
/////////////////////////
Eayes
4,228,223
Elhyjtyjey
1,456,729
1,412,750
Lein
243
184
AA
1,129
672
Elejntyj345hn
002,570
Neerthty34ond
916
78
Biwertetoel
910,353
Qen
874,812
Bs
877,293
Pyd
850,146
1978Q1
/////////////////////////
```

I tried following regex but not working for me:

```
^/////////////////////////\R((?:(?!^/////////////////////////).)*)\R\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=\R)
^(?:(?!^/////////////////////////).)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=\R/////////////////////////)
```

how to do this by regex in notepad++?
in other words regex must bookmark all lines before my regex matches until last line include `/////////////////////////` and all lines after my regex matches until first line include `/////////////////////////`

Comment: Thanks for posting your efforts and samples in your question. Could you please do elaborate more on what is the criteria for getting expected output? Since you want to highlight whole section itself.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 my list splited by ///////////////////////// and my regex each matches placed between two of /////////////////////////. I want to bookmark between two of ///////////////////////// that placed by each regex matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the matches in between, you can start the match with only forward slashes on a line.

Then use `\K` to not include it in the match, and continue matching all lines that do not have at least 2 consecutive lines matching the numbers.

Then match at least 2 consecutive lines with the numbers and continue matching all lines that do not contains only forward slashes and assert at the end that there is a line containing only forward slashes.

```
^/+\R\K(?:(?!/+$|\d+(?:,\d+)*\R\d+(?:,\d+)*$).*\R)*\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\R\d+(?:,\d+)*)+(?:\R(?!/+$).*)*(?=\R/+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1vEjb/1)

Or a bit shorter and a bit more permissive variant:

```
^/+\R\K(?:(?!/+$|\d[\d,]*\R\d[\d,]*$).*\R)*\d[\d,]*(?:\R\d[\d,]*)+(?:\R(?!/+$).*)*(?=\R/+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Wuj9G/1)